# Advisory locking interface for c in windows

Tags: c, windows

I work on linux. Iam writing a locking interface.

In linux the default locking is advisory locking where as in windows  it is mandatory locking with LOCKFILE interface. I want a advisory locking interface in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Why not look at how cygwin does it, or simply use cygwin? Another possibility would be using the creation and removal of lock files as locks.